# Ember.js install on Windows: Will not load app: Cannot find module 'ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app'

Tags: ember.js, npm

Just installed ember.js on Windows machine (XP) - new to ember.js setting up dev machine.

Necessary components seem to be present and responsive.

$ember version gives me:

```
version: 0.2.3
node: 0.12.2
npm: 2.7.6
```

$npm version gives me:

```
{ alquimista: '0.0.0',
  npm: '2.7.4',
  http_parser: '2.3',
  modules: '14',
  node: '0.12.2',
  openssl: '1.0.1m',
  uv: '1.4.2-node1',
  v8: '3.28.73',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
```

**Revision**

$ bower list

```
app Y:\webwork\emberjs\alquimista\app
```

When I switch to my ember app directory and run

$ember server

I get an error

```
version: 0.2.3
Cannot find module 'ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app'
Error: Cannot find module 'ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Y:\webwork\emberjs\alquimista\Brocfile.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

Yes, I have confirmed "ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app" exists and is in the PATH variable in a fully qualified form, c:/.. etc . But the error msg does not contain the fully qualified path so I wonder if ember.js is using a relative path on load? I don't know what base directory it would be starting from and referencing based on.

Does anyone have a suggested fix to get the ember server running on a Windows machine in a case like this?

Answer (score 2):

Seems related to this issue over at the `ember-cli` GitHub repository: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3961

As @ebryn states, `npm install && bower install` should help :)

In general, the setup should be as follows (on windows):

- Install latest `node.js`
- Install `bower` via `npm install -g bower`
- Install `phantomjs` via `npm install phantomjs`
- Install `ember-cli` via `npm install ember-cli@0.2.3`

and you should be good to go :)

Comment: Thanks, but all those components are installed if you notice, I posted the installed versions in the question blocks.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just reposted these steps as I'm working on Win7 and Win8.1 machines and those steps where all I needed and I just thought I'll repost the steps to maybe start from scratch, but as I see you found your way :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `npm install` ?

Also, you will need to run `bower install` to grab the front-end dependencies.

Comment: Is $ bower install a separate package than the ember.js install glob from the fine folks at ember.js here?http://emberjs.com/builds/#/release

Comment: Ran this - npm install -g bower. Restarted the shell -- Error is verbatim the same. Weird. I hate tracking down windows setup  issues. Bleh.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, but the answer for a working Windows XP ember.js install is the following steps. I'm pretty sure it is a relative path issue problem with Windows and ember, but this seems to work around that issue:

```
// Setup node 1st

$node install
$node --version (to confirm good install)
// Note: Installs in system's Documents and Settings tree, weird, but okay

// IMPORTANT THING
//--> **Cd to the directory where you plan to create your application**

$npm -g install ember-cli
$ember -- version (to confirm good install)

// In the same directory, create the app tree with boilerplate code with this command
$ember new my-app-name

// Go have coffee, come back and enter the commands
$cd my-app-name
$ember server
```

Comment: So, did you follow the steps which are given over at http://www.ember-cli.com/#getting-started in the first place (before you posted your question) and it wasn't working until you started again from scratch with the steps you posted? If so, you should probably consider to raise an issue over at the `ember-cli` GitHub repo to add additional/different steps for Windows XP (on Win7 and up the steps in the ember-cli guide are all you need) so that other developers with a XP machine could follow these steps too :+1:

Comment: Yes. I did. Exactly. And in fact, the steps above are their steps with some test verification in between for good measure. But, the key was running the npm install -g ember-cli command in the right directory, which was not specified in the ember,js instructions -- where I wrote "IMPORTANT THING" above. That's for me was *the* key. Maybe it's not required on all dev. platforms to the do this, so it's not included in the generic install. Thank you for the advice to add this to the GitHub repo guide -- great idea!

Comment: Ah, ok. It still makes me wonder that you have to run the global npm install command within the app-directory - this seems very odd :(

Comment: The Brocfile.js seems a suspect as a source of the problem. It contains  hardcoded relative path => var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app'); I'm using mapped networked drives. This has caused issues with other installed software. When I have time to get back to this project, I'll probably try to figure out the exact linkage.